# QtCreator move file

Tags: file, path, move

In QtCreator isn't possible, when you are in File System view, to move file to others location. I have to use the operating system file system and correct all include path manually.

[File System picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSPEQ.png)

Here i would like to move frequency.cpp & frequency.h to the Analysis directory. I don't know how to do that with an assistance from QtCreator, save lot of time and avoid bugs.

Comment: Could you provide a more specific title for your question?